# Can someone please explain me the meaning of these lines about power sets from Halmos' Naive set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please refer page 20 of Halmos' Naive set theory.

"If $\Bbb E$ is a collection of subsets of a set $E$ (that is, $\Bbb E$ is a subcollection of $\mathcal P (E)$) then write

$$\mathscr D = \{X \in \mathcal P(E) : X' \in \Bbb E\}$$

(To be certain that the condition used in the definition of $\mathscr D$ is a sentence in the precise technical sense, it must be rewritten in something like the form

*for some $Y[Y \in \Bbb E$ and for all $x (x \in X$ if and only if $(x \in E$ and $x \in' Y))]$*

I am not able to understand which elements does the new set $\mathscr D$ precisely contains. Most importantly, what does the condition in the definition of $\mathscr D$ really says?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apologies for so many edits, but it took me a while to find all the mistakes. It is *essential* that a precise understanding of the words "the" and "a" is learned.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. To be honest it took me 15 minutes just to type this question. I had to look up all the LaTeX commands and composed this question in a hurry. I've understood your edits and I'll keep these things in my mind from now on.

Comment: Puzzling. There's very little to look up. Apart from the specific fonts (of which I'd have used different ones) and the backslash before the { and } for the set notations, everything is just entered as is, and surrounded by dollar signs.

Comment: I'll do better next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\mathcal D$ consists of those subsets $X$ of $E$ such that $X^\complement\in\Bbb E$; in other words, it consists of those subsets $X$ of $E$ such that $E\setminus X\in\Bbb E$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looming around the same idea but your comment gave me a proper explanation.